# How should I implement a timeout in a GRPC call?

Tags: go, grpc

I am using this code to connect to a grpc server and `clientConn` object is used for all subsequent rpc calls. `maxDelay` is set to 5 seconds. Now because of some issue at server, it is not responding for a grpc call. So my client is waiting for a long time for each rpc call. Do I need to set timeout in a different way?

```
b := grpc.BackoffConfig{
        MaxDelay: maxDelay,
}

clientConn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddress, grpc.WithBackoffConfig(b), grpc.WithInsecure())

if err != nil {
        log.Println("Dial failed!")
        return err
}
```

Comment: `MaxDelay` may not be correct, you need to set the Time out of deadline, so that the connection throw error / exception on timeout, check the links
https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/

Comment: Backoff delays are not timeouts. They specify the amount of time to wait between retries. Use the contexts for timeouts and/or cancellation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify your code to add a timeout using `grpc.WithTimeout(5 * time.Second)` instead of using `MaxDelay` and `grpc.WithBackoffConfig(b)` which are for retries and retries delay.

```
clientConn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddress, grpc.WithTimeout(5 * time.Second), grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
        log.Println("Dial failed!")
        return err
}
```

However the above is deprecated, alternatively you can use `DialContext` and `context.WithTimeout`

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)

clientConn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, serverAddress, grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Dial failed!")
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The doc of `WithTimeout` says that it is used to set timeout of connection initializing, and not to set timeout to the calls. context in the DialContext is the same.

> WithTimeout returns a DialOption that configures a timeout for dialing
> a ClientConn initially. This is valid if and only if WithBlock() is
> present. Deprecated: use DialContext instead of Dial and
> context.WithTimeout instead. Will be supported throughout 1.x.

To set timeout to the calls you can pass `context` to `invoke` like:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(ctx, time.Now().Add(time.Duration(2000)*time.Millisecond))
defer cancel()
clientConn.Invoke(ctx, "/YourEndpoint", in, out, opts...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `context.WithTimeout` is used in the `grpc.DialContext` to control the timeout of all RPC calls of the current DialContext. It is inconvenient to handle the different timeouts of one/some specific RPC call.

---

We could define one custom timeout `callOption` to handle the forced timeout value of some RPC calls in the `clientInterceptor`

Define the custom timeout `callOption` through [`EmptyCallOption`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#EmptyCallOption)

```golang
type TimeoutCallOption struct {
    grpc.EmptyCallOption

    forcedTimeout time.Duration
}

func WithForcedTimeout(forceTimeout time.Duration) TimeoutCallOption {
    return TimeoutCallOption{forcedTimeout: forceTimeout}
}
```

Handle the `forcedTimeout` in the `UnaryClientInterceptor`

```golang
func getForcedTimeout(callOptions []grpc.CallOption) (time.Duration, bool) {
    for _, opt := range callOptions {
        if co, ok := opt.(TimeoutCallOption); ok {
            return co.forcedTimeout, true
        }
    }

    return 0, false
}

func TimeoutInterceptor(t time.Duration) grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor {
    return func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply interface{}, cc *grpc.ClientConn,
        invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
        timeout := t
        if v, ok := getForcedTimeout(opts); ok {
            timeout = v
        }

        if timeout <= 0 {
            return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
        }

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
        defer cancel()

        return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
    }
}
```

Usage samples

```golang
// The default timeout of RPC call of this conn is 3 seconds
conn, err := grpc.Dial(
        address,
grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(TimeoutInterceptor(time.Duration(3)*time.Second)), ...)

....

c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
c.SayHello(context.Background(), &pb.HelloRequest{Name: "world"},
            WithForcedTimeout(time.Duration(10)*time.Second))
// The timeout of SayHello RPC call is 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The old syntax using `grpc.WithTimeout` is deprecated.

```golang
opts := []grpc.DialOption{
  // you would also need grpc.WithBlock() which can be an anti-pattern
  // grpc.WithBlock(),
  grpc.WithTimeout(timeoutValue),
  // ...
}
clientConn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddress, opts...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithTimeout

> `WithTimeout` returns a `DialOption` that configures a timeout for dialing a `ClientConn` initially. This is valid if and only if `WithBlock()` is present.
>
> Deprecated: use `DialContext` instead of `Dial` and `context.WithTimeout` instead. Will be supported throughout 1.x.

So if you use the new syntax, that is still only applicable to a timeout for dialing the initial `ClientConn`.

```golang
opts := []grpc.DialOption{
  ...
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeoutValue)
clientConn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, serverAddress, opts...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

> I am using this code to connect to a grpc server and clientConn object is used for all subsequent rpc calls. maxDelay is set to 5 seconds. Now because of some issue at server, it is not responding for a grpc call. So my client is waiting for a long time for each rpc call. Do I need to set timeout in a different way?

If you want a timeout on each call; then that's beyond the initial `ClientConn`. You would want instead to provide use `context.WithTimeout` and pass that to `ClientConn.Invoke`. So you could either do that yourself, or configure an interceptor for the timeout.

https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.Invoke

There are 2 nice packages to use for configuring common client interceptors for timeouts and retries:

- https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/tree/main/interceptors/retry
- https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/tree/main/interceptors/timeout

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/v2/interceptors/timeout"
)

opts := []grpc.DialOption{
    // timeout for each unary call
    timeout.UnaryClientInterceptor(timeoutValue),
    // ...
}

// timeout for initial ClientConn
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeoutValue)
clientConn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, serverAddress, opts...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: `go-grpc-middleware` seems to have changed. To create a `grpc.DialOption` from an interceptor one has to invoke `grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(timeout.UnaryClientInterceptor(timeoutValue))` now, so let the function implement the `DialOption` interface.